# Choosing appropriate models for the case studies

Tags: uml

As I read through UML user guide chapter1, Principles of Modeling the First principle is

> The choice of what models to create has a profound influence on how a
>   problem is attacked and how a solution is shaped In other words,
>   choose your models well. The right models will brilliantly illuminate
>   the most wicked development problems, offering insight that you simply
>   could not gain otherwise; the wrong models will mislead you, causing
>   you to focus on irrelevant issues.

1- **I wonder if there is considerations I should take it into account while choosing UML models for a problem?**

2- **Where can I find this type of information?**

Comment: @George Stocker, I updated my question.Could you please check it?

Comment: Thanks for trying to improve your question; the problem is that answers will be very long (indeed there are entire books written on UML and real world applications); so 'considerations' is broad. Also, "Where can I find this type of information" points to asking for third party resources, which (due to the turbulent nature of the internet) is off topic for our site.  If you've got a specific problem with something you've been trying to model, we could help -- but as it stands this question has a few issues 1) It's way too broad, 2) asks for off site resources 3) can't be answered succinctly.